# valueinjecter not copying nested properties values

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, mapping, valueinjecter

I have following class:

```
public class Ad
{
    public int Id {get;set;}

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string UrlTitle { get; set; }

    public LookUp Color {get;set}

    public LookUp Condition {get;set}

    public int InsertUserId {get; set;}

    public DateTime InsertDate {get; set;}
}
```

LookUp class is as follows:

```
public class LookUp
{
     public int Id {get;set;}

     public string Name { get; set; } 

     public int InsertUserId {get; set;}

     public DateTime InsertDate {get; set;}
}
```

Then I have ViewModels for these classes like:

```
public class AdModel
{
    public int Id {get;set;}

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string UrlTitle { get; set; }

    public LookUpModel Color {get;set}

    public LookUpModel Condition {get;set}
}

public class LookUpModel
{
     public int Id {get;set;}

     public string Name { get; set; } 
}
```

Now in my controller, I am doing something like this:

```
public IHttpActionResult Get(int adId)
{
    var ad = AdService.Get(adId);//Getting ad from DB

    AdModel adModel = new AdModel();
    adModel.InjectFrom(ad);
    return Ok(adModel);
}
```

My problem is `ValueInjecter` is only copying the first level properties of the Ad like `Id, Title, UrlTitle` but it is not copying the `LookUp` into `LookUpModel` property.

Comment: seems like the AdModel class does not have the method "InjectFrom" ...

Comment: I am using valueinjecter, InjectFrom method is provided by ValueInjecter.

Comment: use `Mapper.Map` instead of `.InjectFrom` read about it here: https://github.com/omuleanu/ValueInjecter ;

you'll need to call `Mapper.AddMap` for each pair of types before mapping (and call Mapper.Map inside of AddMap)

Comment: No even Mapper.Map didn't work but I found one solution here http://qubanshi.cc/questions/950728/omu-valueinjecter-deep-clone-unlike-types, it works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**@Usman Khalid:** you can use serialize and deserialize objects using newtonsoft JSON library.
and then used injectfrom method on the deserializing object your problem maybe resolve.

```
example: Admodel model = new Admodel();
 var s = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);
 UserModel user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserModel>(s);
user.InjectFrom(user);
```